# Calculation of $\int \frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z - (\frac 1 2 + \frac i 2))((z - (-\frac 1 2 - \frac i 2)))}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Recently I was reading something and I met calculations of this integral which I don't quite understand:
$$\int_{\partial B(0 , 1)} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z - (\frac 1 2 +  \frac i 2))((z - (-\frac 1 2 -  \frac i 2)))} dz$$
They divide $\partial B(0, 1)$ into two line segments of smaller balls. First ($C_1$) lying in first quarter, and second ($C_2$) in third quarter (or so, its quite unclear what they did).

Then they said that:

$$\int_{\partial B(0 , 1)} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z - (\frac 1 2 +  \frac i 2))((z - (-\frac 1 2 -  \frac i 2)))} dz = \int_{C_1} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z - (\frac 1 2 +  \frac i 2))} dz + \int_{C_2} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z - (-\frac 1 2 -  \frac i 2))} dz$$

The rest of the proof is trivial, but I don't undestand how this partition can work. Could you please explain to me what exactly did the mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can do  partial fraction decomposition, after setting $z=e^{i\phi}$, and you obtain the two integrals you have. [See here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial%20fraction%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ApartCalculator%22%2C%20%22rationalfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22e%5E%28%CF%80%20e%5E%28i%5Cphi%29%29%2F%28%28e%5E%28i%5Cphi%29-%20%281%2F2%20%2B%20i%2F2%29%29%20%28e%5E%28i%5Cphi%29%20-%20%28-1%2F2%20-%20i%2F2%29%29%29%22)